# How to make dotted physics shooter simulator like bubble shooter

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to achieve something like this:
[image: example]

I've already done something similar using the Unity particle system. It works fine but the problem is when you rotate the pointer, a wave is formed. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the wave using particle effects, you will need to move each particle immediately by how much it needs to move to get into its new position. The reason you get a wave now is because you're only changing the emitter's direction.

Instead, it might be a better approach to use a **wrapped** `LineRenderer` and scrolling the UVs on the texture/renderer on each `Update` using `lineRenderer.material.SetTextureOffset`. You'll also need to calculate the points to draw the line, and set those as appropriate in `Update` as well.

This way, when you change the aim, the `LineRenderer`'s positions can all move accordingly and the dots will always appear to be in a series of straight lines.

Comment: Thanks . have a look at this link this is i have done so far https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RgRD8ulvdGKnLoWnOy_WWRHuOy6muyVo/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Increase the speed of the Simulation Speed in the main (top) section of the Particle Settings. Try 10, to start with. You might need even higher. Default is 1.

Comment: i have increased the speed 10 will be much higher as dots will seem like bullets

Comment: You'll need to find a visual harmonics rate that prevents visual movement of the particles. This will take a little fiddling.